# method overloading with routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, overloading

I would like to code two functions with same name and different parameters in controller as below.

```
[Route("Home/index")]
public JsonResult index()
{
    return new JsonResult {Data = 'test1'};
}

[Route("Home/index/{id}")]
public JsonResult index(id)
{
    return new JsonResult {Data = 'test2'};
}
```

But I got an the following error with this.

> The current request for action 'index' on controller type
>   'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult index() on type
>   application.Controllers.HomeController System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult
>   index(int) on type application.Controllers.HomeController

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this. The code is working but it need to insert following code in RouteConfig.cs.

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something as you can define multiple routes

```
[Route("index")]
[Route("index/{id}")]
public JsonResult index(int id = null)
{

    if(id.HasValue()){
      return new JsonResult {Data = 'test2'};
    }

    return new JsonResult {Data = 'test1'};
}
```

Comment: I want to know about method overloading.
I already found and answered.